how to address different behavior
I would like to add a sentence to address different behavior between different version:

If the display is asleep and the user long presses the button, the display will:
( < android13): only wake up and home navigation will not occur.
( >= android13):  wake up and navigate back to the home screen.

What's proper way to address above sentence?

"...the user presses the button for a long time..." - but proofreading is off-topic.

This is fine in technical documentation although you should figure out how to avoid line-breaks after the less than/greater than signs, and remove the spaces after the opening bracket. Also your word processor should let you use ≤ rather than <=. With these changes you're OK, unless you're writing something much more formal. If you want greater formality or something without the signs, you need to tell us exactly what you want.

In a software or programming context (which this is) both 'long press' and '<=' '>=' are not just acceptable but probably preferable. However, I would add a hyphen to 'long-presses'.

The construction here resembles programming logic, with an "if/else" situation. When writing in human language, the best approach is to simply add enough extra words to communicate the concept of "if/else." Many wordings would be possible, but one example might be:

If the display is asleep and the user long presses the button, the behavior will vary, depending on the user's Android version. If the Android version is below 13, the display will wake up but home navigation will not occur. On version 13 and higher, the display will wake up and the device will navigate back to the home screen.

I made a few wording tweaks in addition to introducing the "conditional" language because navigation is not really something that "the display" does.

It's pedantic, but 'long-press' requires a hyphen.

Or ... perhaps 'requires' is too strong. There are good stylistic reasons for hyphenating new or seldom-used compound verbs.

The answer to this question is really a matter of context. If used in a relatively technical context where brevity is required, all I would suggest is better punctuation:

If the display is asleep and the user long-presses the button, the display will:

(< Android 13) only wake up. Home navigation will not occur.
( >= Android 13) wake up and navigate back to the home screen.


I checked and the correct name for the Android OS version 13 is 'Android 13', not 'android13'.
Stylistically, dividing point 1) into two sentences, rather than using 'and home navigation ...' makes the distinction between 1) and 2) much clearer to the reader.
If you are in a context where more 'formal' or 'literary' English is required, and word length is not a consideration, then I would use the answer provided by @Andy-Bonnar. However, note I would personally strongly recommend adding a hyphen to 'long-presses' in his answer as 'to long-press' is a compound verb (and a relatively new one).

Phones with different Android versions will behave differently under this program.
If the display is asleep and the user long presses the button, the display will
. only wake up, and home navigation will not occur, for Android versions older than 13
. wake up and navigate back to the home screen for Android 13 and newer.

Bullet points do provide a way to address the situation, though they may not be stylistically appropriate everywhere (fine in a PowerPoint or pamphlet, not in academic prose), and I'd prefer a version that still worked grammatically when read through.

OP wants help with programming - What's proper way to address above sentence?

Thanks,@Andy Bonner.  Agreed.  The original post was earlier in point form.  I thought that was the OP’s intention and hence didn’t change it to a paragraph.
